# Can a variadic template match a non-variadic template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, variadic

Consider the following snippet:

```
template<template<class> class T,class U>
struct apply
{
     typedef T<U> type;
};

typedef apply<std::tuple,int>::type tuple_of_one_int; //Should be std::tuple<int>
```

GCC 4.8.2. says:

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for [...] struct apply
expected a template of type ‘template<class> class T’, got ‘template<class ...> class std::tuple’
```

Which basically means that a variadic template like `std::tuple` is not a valid template argument for `T` in `apply`.

Is this a GCC bug or does the standard mandates this behaviour?

Comment: I think the compiler is correct. You have to write `template<typename T> using my_tuple = std::tuple<T>; 
typedef apply<my_tuple, int>::type tuple_of_one_int`.

Comment: I would expect it to be standard behavior, clang does the same. As for workaround use alias `template<class T> using tupl = std::tuple<T>;`.

Comment: Changing `template<class>` to `template<class...>` makes it work, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like it's correct from this quote:

> 3 A template-argument matches a template template-parameter (call it P) when each of the template parameters in the template-parameter-list of the template-argument’s corresponding class template or [FI 11] template aliasalias template (call it A) matches the corresponding template parameter in the template-parameter-list of P

`A` (the given template) has to match each of it's templates parameters to `P`'s the template template.

From the second part of the section we learn the restriction doesn't apply in the reverse, meaning a template template containing a parameter pack can match anything.

> When P’s template-parameter-list contains a template parameter pack (14.5.3), the template parameter pack will match zero or more template parameters or template parameter packs in the template-parameter- list of A with the same type and form as the template parameter pack in P

As you probably already knew the way to make it work is

```
template<template<class> class T,class U>                                       
struct apply                                                                       
{                                                                                  
         typedef T<U> type;                                                        
};                                                                                 

template<class T> using tuple_type  = std::tuple<T>;
typedef apply<tuple_type,int>::type tuple_of_one_int;
```

The c++11 standard also has an equivalent example to yours.

```
template <class ... Types> class C { /∗ ... ∗/ };

template<template<class> class P> class X { /∗ ... ∗/ };

X<C> xc; //ill-formed: a template parameter pack does not match a template parameter
```

The last comment completely describes your situation, class `C` would be the equivalent of `std::tuple` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is ill-formed, there is equivalent example in the standard (under 14.3.3/2):

```
...
template <class ... Types> class C { /∗ ... ∗/ };

template<template<class> class P> class X { /∗ ... ∗/ };
...
X<C> xc; // ill-formed: a template parameter pack does not match a template parameter
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix:

```
template<template<class...> class T,class U>
struct apply
{
     typedef T<U> type;
};

typedef apply<std::tuple,int>::type tuple_of_one_int;
typedef apply<std::vector,int>::type vector_of_int;
```

Comment: this isn't really a fix since it actually does something different in some situations, check out my answer

Comment: @aaronman It's a fix for the OP's case: `apply` must have a member type `T<U>` where `T` is a given template and `U` is a given **type**. Of course, it doesn't work if `T` requires at least two arguments or if it takes one or more arguments and the first one is a non-type. The code in my post is accepted by gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.3.

Comment: I'm just saying that in your case the struct now takes a template with any number of params, possibly not the original intent, it may or may not be good for the OP